How does SFINAE affects symbol?
Given helpers as follow :
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complete<T, decltype(void(sizeof(T)))> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_complete_v = is_complete<T>::value;

The following two function signature generates the same symbol.
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_complete_v<type<T>>>* = nullptr>
size_t func() {...} // func<MyType> ==  _Z4funcI6MyTypeLPv0EEmv

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_complete_v<type<T>>>* = nullptr>
size_t func(); // func<MyType> == _Z4funcI6MyTypeLPv0EEmv

But the following signatures generates different symbols against each other.
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_complete_v<type<T>>, size_t> func();
// func<MyType> == _Z4funcI6MyTypeENSt9enable_ifIX13is_complete_vI4typeIT_vEEEmE4typeEv

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!is_complete_v<type<T>>, size_t> func();
// func<MyType> == _Z4funcI6MyTypeENSt9enable_ifIXnt13is_complete_vI4typeIT_vEEEmE4typeEv

The environment details:

Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
OS: Ubuntu22.04 Linux 5.15.0-106-generic
gcc: 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
options: -std=gnu++17

My questions are:

As I could tell all those signatures put some template information into symbol. But why are the latter two forms seems more detail ?
Can I rely on the first case, when writing some code across platforms or compilers?

Thanks for your patience.
The reason why I care about this(maybe I should not):
The template function func<T> is designed for user to invoke any time and any where. It has the same body for all Ts, so we should write it only once.
The problem is that, the func relies on the template class type<T> to be defined to work properly. But, sometimes, users are not provided with a type<T> definition. That should not stop users from invoking func<T>. User should be able to invoke func<T> while the type<T> incomplete.
So the signatures shown in the first case were introduced.
In the context where type<T> was defined, the first one is invoked with a function body. Compiler generates code using the definition of type<T>.
While, in the context where type<T> is not defined, the second one is invoked without body. Compiler generates symbol reference without requiring definition of type<T>.
That makes the compiler happy.
Compiler generates the same symbol for the two form, so that the linker is happy too. (Although the definition of type<T> is not provided for user, the implementation of type<T> and func<T> are ready in library file for link.)
The trick described above meets the following two requirements:

The user should be able to invoke func<T> with or without the definition of type<T>.
The function body of func<T> should be written only once.


Symbol names shouldn't concern you unless you're working at the ABI level, but I doubt you are and if you really are, you're probably doing things wrong.


"because the compiler made it so". Maybe the g++ authors have a document somewhere that explains how and why things are done the way they are, but since there's no standard it's pretty pointless to worry about that. 2) since there's no standard, that's a "no". I do like to use boost/type_index.hpp to demangle typenames (although it crashes on some...), but that's just for log outputs so I don't really care about the details, just that it outputs something more readable. Not functions, though -- never had a reason to demangle function symbols in my code.


Can I rely on the first case, when writing some code across platforms or compilers? No.  The name mangling is an implementation detail, and may vary even on the same platform, with the same compiler (and different compiler flags), or the same compiler between compiles, or different versions of the same compiler line.  Let alone across platforms or different compilers.

Implementation details should not be relied upon in general. Write code that is independently.

The reason you added later has nothing to do with symbols, you're asking about using incomplete class templates. It is so different from your original question that you should ask another one, complete with a [mre].

Well, in the solution above, the compiling unit with type definition and the one without type use two different signatures. It is correctly compiled and linked only if the two signature are translated into the same symbol. @Passer By

No, those are all implementation details and your attempted solution. Don't ask about your attempted solution to a question, ask the question itself, which is about what the language allows you to do and ways to work around that. See XY problem.

That makes sense, try this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78484877/16764050 @PasserBy
