How to invoke template function with maybe incomplete type argument
Template function func<T> is designed to be used any where. It has the same function body for any T. I want to write its body only once. But the function depends on the definition type<T> to work properly, and there's no definition of type<T> in some context. See the following example(in C++17):
/// type.h
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct type;

template<typename T>
inline size_t func() {
  return type<T>::magic;
}

template<typename T>
struct type<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>> {
  static constexpr size_t magic = sizeof(T) * 2;
};

/// my_type.h
struct MyStruct {
  int a;

  static void Dummy();
};

/// my_type.cpp
#include "my_type.h"
#include "type.h"

template<>
struct type<MyStruct> {
  static constexpr size_t magic = 123;
};

void MyStruct::Dummy() {
  (void)func<MyStruct>();
}

/// main.cpp
#include "my_type.h"
#include "type.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  func<int>(); // OK
  func<MyStruct>(); // Error
}

How could I manage to do that:

Write the body of func<T> only once.
Make it possible to invoke func<T> when type<T> is incomplete.


note: There's a Dummy function, which is used force the compiler generate code for func<MyStruct> so that the linker will happy.

More details
Q:Why can you not place the specialization in a header that main can include ?
A:The header file type.h is part of a library, and the rest code is the user code. The type<T> specialization of some type T were defined in tool-generated source files which are not allowed to be published with the library.
Q:What do you expect to happen when func<T> is called but there is no definition for type? I don't understand how you expect anything other than a compiler error.
A:The library contains the implementation of func<T> for MyStruct. So it would be nice of compiler to just leave a symbol reference in main.o rather than try to generate the implementation of func and encounter a error.
A work solution provided by Copilot:
The following solution is given by copilot. It works on my machine, but I don't know why(How does SFINAE affects symbol?).
/// type.h
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complete<T, decltype(void(sizeof(T)))> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_complete_v = is_complete<T>::value;

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_complete_v<type<T>>>* = nullptr>
inline size_t func() {...}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_complete_v<type<T>>>* = nullptr>
size_t func();

In the solution above, body of func<T> still need to be written once, and user could invoke func<T> no matter the type<T> is defined or not.
In this solution, someting like MyStruct::Dummy is still needed, because there should be at least one explicitly invoke of func<T> in the context where type<T> is defined. That will make the compiler generate code for func<MyStruct>.

its not possible to return type<T>::magic; when type<T> is not defined. Whats the actualy underlying problem you are trying to solve?

or more narrowly, what do you want to return when you cannot return type<T>::magic?

and yet another try to clarify, why can you not place the specialization in a header that main can include?

What do you expect to happen when func<T> is called but there is no definition for type<T>? I don't understand how you expect anything other than a compiler error.

The implementation is already generated in my_type.h, so it will be nice of the compiler to just leave a symbol reference in main.cpp rather than try to generate the implementation of func and encounter a error. @AndyG

Can you clarify which files are under your control, and which files are from user, and which code is hidden from user?

Under my control: type.h and some of the source file of custom type like .(In this question, my_type.cpp and my_type.h are under my control)
User code: main.cpp
Hidden code: there should be a header/source file named type_my_struct.h/cpp contains the definition of type<MyStruct>. I missed that file on the question text by mistake. @Jarod42

Hint: you could implement the is_complete type trait in a cleaner way: the original class can be defaulted to bool = true instead of typename = void; then, the partial-specialization is specialized with sizeof(T) only.

There is no way to implement is_complete. That's not a question you can ask in a trait.

Use an explicit instantiation: https://godbolt.org/z/d7E48Mdaq
/// my_type.h
#include "type.h"

struct MyStruct {
  int a;
};

// Explicit instantiation declaration
extern template size_t func<MyStruct>();

/// my_type.cpp
#include "my_type.h"
#include "type.h"

template<>
struct type<MyStruct> {
  static constexpr size_t magic = 123;
};

// Explicit instantiation definition
template size_t func<MyStruct>();

Declare that it exists in the header file (so anything that includes the header can see the declaration and not try to instantiate the template itself), and define it in the source file when the type is complete.
You also no longer need Dummy, which wasn't guaranteed to work anyway.

Firstly, thank you for answering my question. But there are some problems about the solution.

The header file type.h is part of a library, and the rest code is the user code. As the author of library, I cannot predict how many custom types like MyStruct really is. So It's not easy for me to hard code the explicit instantiation declaration of func<MyStruct>.
Even for types defined by the library, it's also difficult to do so. Because there are a lot of types needs func<T> and many other functions like func.

And the reason why user context does not have the definition type<T> of some types is that those type<T>s were defined in generated source files which are not allowed to be published with the library.

@王雨泽 If the library has template<typename T> size_t func() {return type<T>::magic;} (or similar), whenever you use func<MyStruct>(), the compiler will always try to instantiate that definition when you use it, unless you've declared something else (like an overload, an explicit full specialization, or like in this answer an explicit instantiation). I don't think it's possible to write this easily with how you've written your functions (except with a macro to declare/define all the explicit instantiations). The other solution is to rewrite your library code in a way that it is possible

There is a work(maybe limited) solution. It was provided by AI. I've updated the question text to share it. What do you think about it ?

Sorry I mixed up some details of your solution. The explicit instantiation is the best replace of the Dummy.
But the extern ... is still too many to be written.

You cannot hide constexpr variable to user.
I think you can generate your code differently:
/// type.h
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct type
{
    static const size_t magic; // Declaration only
};

// Specialization for builtin types
template<typename T>
struct type<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>> {
  static constexpr size_t magic = sizeof(T) * 2;
};

template<typename T>
size_t func() { return type<T>::magic; }


/// my_type.h
struct MyStruct {
  int a;
};

/// my_type.cpp // Generated code
#include "my_type.h"
#include "type.h"

/*static*/ const size_t type<MyStruct>::magic = 123; // Definition

/// main.cpp
#include "my_type.h"
#include "type.h"

int main() {
  func<int>();
  func<MyStruct>();
}

if user want to customize for its own type, type<MyUserType>::magic has to be defined.
